# How to use/incorporate CPP files to Android project?

Tags: android, c++, ios, android-ndk, java-native-interface

We have developed an iPad application where the core logic is written in CPP code, so that we can use the same code files/libraries to other platforms.

Now I want to use those files and develop similar Android application, but unable to create .so files and integrate paths in Android.mk files and all. I am basically an iOS developer, this is first time I am looking into Android NDK.

Can anyone help and guide if there is any straight forward steps to it.

I have already gone through android developers site and few other tutorial sites. But none of those worked for me.

Require easy-clear steps to call cpp method in java, if I do have few cpp files and .a libraries with me already.

Comment: Have you already read https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html ?

Comment: Please post some code and explain : what you managed to do, where precisely you're stucked

Comment: Sounds like a job for [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't very specific at the step you are stuck at.

Here's a very quick explanation on how to call native code from java (android) :

- first create a method to be exported by the native and called by java (this uses JNI, so  google JNI , JNIEXPORT)
- once you have this method defined in your native code, it's time to create a shared library (.so) file , using the compiler that comes in the NDK (because you are compiling for android ). You will need to compile for the correct architecture of the device (armeabiv7s is the most common now days).
- you need to add the library file in your app.apk inside the armeabi folder (more details in NDK tutorials).
- inside your java code you will need to load the shared library via the System.loadLibrary(LIBRARY_NAME);
- inside your java code you will need to have defined static native methods that are in pair with the methods you exported from your CPP code

Quick tips :

- use C functions,not CPP , since CPP will be mangled in the resulting shared library. In other words, you will need to create a C wrapper that will call your cpp code.
- look over a hello world tutorial for NDK , and work yourself from there .  Here's a link to such tutorial http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/hello-world-example-using-ndk-in-android/

You will bump later on into compilation issues with the makefiles, but by then you will probably be able to be more specific with your question.

Comment: Thanks, let me try the steps from the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the hello-jni Android studio sample project.

There are a lot of settings and configurations, you get them from the sample that is a working unit, always easiest when starting from something working.

First run (and modify) the hello-jni and learn how the interactivity between the Java and C parts works. About everything works except environmental ANSI C/C++ stuff. You have to get things like language, country etc from Java and transfer it to the C-code. You are in US in English with "inches and gallons" in JNI.

Then to an own project you create with android studio, copy and modify from it bit by bit from hello-jni. When you have our own branded hello-JNI you can add bit by bit your own code. Often using C-dummies for testing the interactivity with the Java part is easier, then change it to the real C/C++ code of yours.

Read the Android/Android studio documentation and learn and understand. Use the Android emulators, much easier and they are good.

The project configuration stuff is by far the hardest to handle at the start. If I would make a new project today, I would start from the Hello-JNI once again.